# Is there any difference between in? function between rails 3 and rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

When I migrated to rails 4.2 from rails 3.2, I am getting this error saying, `wrong number of arguments 2 for 1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
In rails 3, Array.in? can write like this

```
'a'.in?('a','b','c','d') => true
```

But in rails 4, it accepts only one argument.
Either, `'a'.in?('a')`
Or, `'a'.in?(['a','b','c','d'])`
Otherwise, it throws an exception